# Converting Activity to use Fragments?

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, tabs

I basically have an activity that has tabs. I want it so that when I select a different tab the fragment at the bottom changes to the selected tab. I know that theres 2 ways to do it. 1 is reload the same grid view with new data. I want it so that I can switch between tabs and it loads all the grid views as you left them. Is this possible and how can I modify this code to support that:

MainActivity:

```
package com.td.flickrsearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.td.flickrsearch.entity.FlickrPhoto;
import com.td.flickrsearch.image.ImageCache.ImageCacheParams;
import com.td.flickrsearch.image.ImageFetcher;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, TabListener {

    private int mImageThumbSize;
    private int mImageThumbSpacing;
    private ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;

    public static int currentPage = 1;
    private boolean endOfAlbums = false;
    private int lastItem = 0;

    private TextView tvNoAlbums;
    private ProgressBar progressLoadMore;

    GridView albumGrid;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    ArrayList<FlickrPhoto> _feed = new ArrayList<FlickrPhoto>();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable updateRunnable;

    EditText etSearch;
    Button btnSearch;

    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_fragment);


           // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Friends").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Chat").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Me").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Users").setTabListener(this));
        //actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section3).setTabListener(this));




        // Set the Animation time form the android defaults
        mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        // ////////////////////////////////////////
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching images, please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // ////////////////////////////////////////

        // /////////////////////////////////////////
        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
        // /////////////////////////////////////////

        mImageThumbSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_thumbnail_size);
        mImageThumbSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_thumbnail_spacing);
        // ////////////////////////////////////////////
        ImageCacheParams cacheParams = new ImageCacheParams(this, Util.IMAGE_CACHE_DIR);

        // The ImageFetcher takes care of loading images into our ImageView
        // children asynchronously
        mImageFetcher = new ImageFetcher(this, mImageThumbSize);
        mImageFetcher.setLoadingImage(R.drawable.empty_photo);
        mImageFetcher.addImageCache(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), cacheParams);
        // ////////////////////////////////////////////

        progressLoadMore = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progressLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // //////////////////////////////////////////////S

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        albumGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.photoGrid);
        tvNoAlbums = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNoAlbums);

        albumGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        albumGrid.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        // This listener is used to get the final width of the GridView and then
        // calculate the
        // number of columns and the width of each column. The width of each
        // column is variable
        // as the GridView has stretchMode=columnWidth. The column width is used
        // to set the height
        // of each view so we get nice square thumbnails.
        albumGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                    final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(albumGrid.getWidth() / (mImageThumbSize + mImageThumbSpacing));
                    if (numColumns > 0) {
                        final int columnWidth = (albumGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mImageThumbSpacing;
                        imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                        imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // albumGrid on item click:
        albumGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long arg3) {
                // On click
                // Display the zoomed in image in full screen
                zoomImageFromThumb(v, pos);
            }
        });

        albumGrid.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
                // Pause fetcher to ensure smoother scrolling when flinging
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                    mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(true);
                } else {
                    mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                final int _lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                if (_lastItem > 0 && totalItemCount > 0)
                    if (_lastItem == _feed.size() && !endOfAlbums && lastItem != _lastItem) {
                        lastItem = _lastItem;
                        // Last item is fully visible.
                        loadAlbums(etSearch.getText().toString().trim());
                    }
            }
        });

        etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    _feed.clear();
                    currentPage = 1;
                    Util.hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
                    loadAlbums(etSearch.getText().toString().trim());
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });




    }





    @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

        return true;
      } 

      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Take appropriate action for each action item click
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                // search action
                Toast.makeText(this, "Search selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_help:
                // help action
                  Toast.makeText(this, "help selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_refresh:
                // refresh
                Toast.makeText(this, "refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSearch:
            // perform search
            _feed.clear();
            currentPage = 1;
            Util.hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
            loadAlbums(etSearch.getText().toString().trim().replaceAll(" ", ""));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    private void loadAlbums(final String tag) {

        if (currentPage == 1) {
            _feed.clear();
            endOfAlbums = false;
            lastItem = 0;
            // get new photos
            progressDialog.show();
        } else
            progressLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (Util.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<FlickrPhoto> serverAlbums;
                    // get the serverAlbums
                    serverAlbums = FlickrParser.getPhotos(tag, currentPage);
                    if (serverAlbums.size() > 0)
                        _feed.addAll(serverAlbums);
                    else
                        endOfAlbums = true;

                    currentPage++;

                    myHandler.post(updateRunnable);
                }
            }).start();
            updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (_feed.size() > 0) {
                        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // get listview current position - used to maintain
                        // scroll position
                        int currentPosition = albumGrid.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                        // Setting new scroll position
                        albumGrid.smoothScrollToPosition(currentPosition + 1, 0);
                    } else
                        tvNoAlbums.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            };
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.check_connectivity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    // ///////////////////////////Zoom in Image///////////////////////////////
    private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int pos) {
        // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it immediately and
        // proceed with this one.
        if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
            mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
        }

        // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
        final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
        // mImageFetcher.loadImage(Util.getPhotoUrlLarge(_feed.get(pos)),
        // expandedImageView);
        mImageFetcher.loadImage(Util.getPhotoUrl(_feed.get(pos)), expandedImageView);

        // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
        // This step
        // involves lots of math. Yay, math.
        final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
        final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
        final Point globalOffset = new Point();

        // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
        // and the
        // final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container view.
        // Also
        // set the container view's offset as the origin for the bounds, since
        // that's
        // the origin for the positioning animation properties (X, Y).
        thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
        findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
        startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
        finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

        // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
        // bounds using the
        // "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable stretching during
        // the animation.
        // Also calculate the start scaling factor (the end scaling factor is
        // always 1.0).
        float startScale;
        if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
            // Extend start bounds horizontally
            startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
            float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
            float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
            startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
            startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
        } else {
            // Extend start bounds vertically
            startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
            float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
            float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
            startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
            startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
        }

        // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
        // begins,
        // it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the thumbnail.
        thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations to the
        // top-left corner of
        // the zoomed-in view (the default is the center of the view).
        expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
        expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

        // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
        // scale properties
        // (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimator = set;

        // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down to the
        // original bounds
        // and show the thumbnail instead of the expanded image.
        final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
        expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                    mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
                }

                // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
                // back to their
                // original values.
                AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
                set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
                set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }
                });
                set.start();
                mCurrentAnimator = set;
            }
        });
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // ///////////////// ADAPTER ////////////////////////////////
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mItemHeight = 0;
        private int mNumColumns = 0;
        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return _feed.size();
        }

        public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
            mNumColumns = numColumns;
        }

        public int getNumColumns() {
            return mNumColumns;
        }

        public void setItemHeight(int height) {
            if (height == mItemHeight) {
                return;
            }
            mItemHeight = height;
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public FlickrPhoto getItem(int position) {
            return _feed.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                holder.cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
                holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            holder.cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

            // Check the height matches our calculated column width
            if (holder.cover.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
                holder.cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            }

            FlickrPhoto photo = getItem(position);
            mImageFetcher.loadImage(Util.getPhotoUrl(photo), holder.cover);
            holder.cover.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.title.setText(photo.getTitle());

            return view;
        }

    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView cover;
        TextView title;
    }








    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {

        } 
        else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {

    }



        else {

            //AndroidVersionList androidversionlist = new AndroidVersionList();
            //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, androidversionlist).commit();
            /*Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, tab.getPosition() + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();*/
        }

    }





    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


ActivityMain.xml:
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />


ListFragment.xml:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/edit_search"
            android:hint="tag name"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Go!" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/photoGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llSearch"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/photo_thumbnail_size"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/photo_thumbnail_spacing"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/photo_thumbnail_spacing" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoAlbums"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No photos to display!"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now I think the best way to do it is probably separate the adapter, make this into separate fragments. Would I be able to switch back to the fragment and will it be in the state I left it in?

So for example if a user scrolled down in the gridview when I switch back to the fragment will it be at the same position with the same data?

It would be great if you could help me convert this into something that will do that. I dont really know much about it so all help is really appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: I want to make something like on iphones you can switch between tabs on the tabbarcontroller and all lists are in the same state when you switch back to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that:

when you do your fragment transactions, remember to add the fragment to the backstack `public abstract FragmentTransaction addToBackStack (String name)` so that you can find the fragment later instead of having the garbage collector destroy your fragment.

When you add your fragment to the backstack, it will do :
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
         .... Save whatever else is uniqe about your fragment here
    }

When you go back to your fragment, since you added it to the backstack, use :

```
onViewStateRestored()
Called when all saved state has been restored into the view hierarchy of the fragment. 
This can be used to do initialization based on saved state that you are letting the view 
hierarchy track itself, such as whether check box widgets are currently checked. This is
called after onActivityCreated(Bundle) and before onStart().
```

Comment: What can I do to make the current code into using fragments though? Im not too sure how to handle it with the gridview and stuff. Can you help me modify it? so I can use the thing you just mentioned :)

Comment: So basically I want to make 2 or 3 fragments made from the gridview code I posted above and I can switch between the gridviews using the tabs.

Comment: I would make the fragment classes, and initialize their views in `onCreateView`. Then I would save the location of how far down they have been scrolled in `onSaveInstanceState`. I would then restore the saved setting on the gridviews in `onViewStateRestored'.                  For the activity, you just need to do :                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction(); transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);transaction.addToBackStack("some tag name for fragment");transaction.commit();

Comment: Yeah but the problem is this is a normal activity I tried changing it to a fragment thats why it says fragmentActivity. How can I make a fragment out of this so I can load the gridview as a fragment as many times as I need. Can you modify it to be a fragment so I can actually load it as a fragment.